# Why am I getting a warning for this range-based for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, warnings, compiler-warnings

I am currently self-teaching myself C++ using Bjarne Stroustrup's book (2nd ed). In one of the examples, he uses a range-for-loop to read the elements in a vector. When I wrote and compiled the code for myself I get this warning. When I run the code, it seems to be working and calculates the mean. Why am I receiving this warning and should I ignore it? Also, why is the range-for using int instead of double in the example, but still returns a double?

```
temp_vector.cpp:17:13: warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 
extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
```

This is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  vector<double> temps;     //initialize a vector of type double

  /*this for loop initializes a double type vairable and will read all 
    doubles until a non-numerical input is detected (cin>>temp)==false */
  for(double temp; cin >> temp;)
    temps.push_back(temp);

  //compute sum of all objects in vector temps
  double sum = 0;

 //range-for-loop: for all ints in vector temps. 
  for(int x : temps)     
    sum += x;

  //compute and print the mean of the elements in the vector
      cout << "Mean temperature: " << sum / temps.size() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

On a similar note: how should I view the range-for in terms of a standard for loop?

Comment: Add `-std=c++11` to your compilation options

Answer (score 26):

Since nobody is showing *how* to use C++ 11 with g++, it looks like this...

```
g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program
```

Hopefully this saves Google visitors an extra search.

Comment: I did end up figuring out how to do this eventually but it's exactly what I needed at the time. I hope it does as well. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a more permanent way to fix this instead of always having to type this out ? I am using g++ with Apple clang 14

Answer (score 21):

Pass `--std=c++11` to the compiler; your (ancient) compiler is defaulting to C++03 and warning you that it is accepting some newer C++ constructs as extensions.

---

Ranged base for is expanded into an iterator-based for loop, but with less opportunities for typos.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm using g++ on mac through the terminal.

Comment: As said: pass "--std=c++11" to the compiler options.

Comment: Is there a way to always compile with c++11/14 by default using g++ command?

Comment: @AbhijeetKhangarot That looks like a good question to ask on stack overflow.  Press the [ask question] button to the top right of this web page (location may vary on mobile).  There are too many subtle details to answer it in a comment, really (aliases, updates, shell scripts among other possibilities).  I am not an expert on the subject, others will be.

Comment: Asked here, if you're interested in answering :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68985458/configuring-c11-14-in-mac-terminal-by-default

Answer (score 9):

For those who use code runner extension on VS code, go to code runner extension settings.
find -> Code-runner:Executer map. Click on edit in `settings.json` and find cpp script for terminal and set it like follows:

```
"cpp": "cd $dir && g++  -std=c++11 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
```

Comment: works as of Jan 2023 in VScode on Code-Runner

Comment: In the version of VSCode current as of 10 May 23, the setting is in tasks.json, as: "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-std=c++17",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `for (int x: temps)` which is a c++11 construct. Try the following if you are using eclipse:

- Right-click on the the project and select "Properties"
- Navigate to C/C++ Build -> Settings
- Select the Tool Settings tab.
- Navigate to GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous
- In the option setting labeled Other Flags add -std=c++11

Now rebuild your project.

**Update:** For Atom follow below steps:

Go to ~/.atom/packages/script/lib/grammers.coffee

Go to the C++ section (ctrl-f c++):

Then change this line:

```
args: (context) -> ['-c', "xcrun clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -Wc++11-extensions // other stuff
```

to this:

```
args: (context) -> ['-c', "xcrun clang++ -fcolor-diagnostics -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ // other stuff
```

i.e. add `-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++` and remove `-Wc++11-extensions`

Hope this helps!

Comment: More recent versions of Eclipse have a Dialect property page under C++ Compiler that allows you to set this more easily

Comment: I'm not using Eclipse, I'm using the Atom text editor and the mac terminal.

Comment: @EfraínGonzález: Added instructions for Atom

Answer (score 0):

For clang users:
use `clang++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`