# warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

hello my code is having the following issue: 
`warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]` for this line of code:
`for (auto val : myTable[i])` How do I fixed this? I couldn't find anything helpful online so I would appreciate step by step guidance (preferably with pictures but I won't complain).

full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;


class hashtable
{

    int capacity;
    list<int> *myTable;

    public:

        hashtable(int capacity)
        {
            this->capacity = capacity;
            myTable = new list<int>[capacity];
        }

        void setList(int hashedIndex, int value)
        {
            myTable[hashedIndex].push_back(value);
        }

        int hashFunction(int value) {
            int retVal = (value * 31) % capacity;
            return retVal;
        }

        void insert(int value) {
            int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);

            cout << "inserted " << value << endl;
            setList(hashedIndex, value);
        }

        void delete_elem(int value)
        {
            if (search(value))
            {
                int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);
                myTable[hashedIndex].remove(value);
            }
        }

        bool search(int value)
        {
            int hashedIndex = hashFunction(value);
            list<int> ::iterator tmp;

            for (list<int> ::iterator itr = myTable[hashedIndex].begin(); itr != myTable[hashedIndex].end(); itr++)
            {
                if (*itr == value)
                {
                    tmp = itr;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return tmp != myTable[hashedIndex].end();
        }

        void printContents() {

            cout << "trying to print contents" << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            {
                cout << i;
                for (auto val : myTable[i]) // issue is on this line
                {
                    cout << " --> " << val;
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    hashtable ht(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ht.insert(i);
    }

    ht.printContents();

    // cout << "yo" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The IDE I'm using is NetBeans

Comment: Why you post so many lines of code if only one line gives the warning. Please post always only the minimum of code a reader must have to help! Thanks! The warning is definitely not helpful. Range based for loop is not an extension, it is simply c++11 standard. So switch on C++11 for your compiler or install an actual one. BTW: We have 2020 and the current standard is C++20, even if the doc is not finalized :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting a warning for this range-based for loop in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269691/why-am-i-getting-a-warning-for-this-range-based-for-loop-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activate c++11 in your compiler option and the warning will disappear :)

It's just a "new" syntax, relative to the C++ 2011 norm, so unless you need backward compatibility with old compilers, you can safely enable c++11 support, or even c++14 or 17.

---

To configure Netbeans, I quote [Ferenc Géczi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14867719/610351):

1. Make sure that you have pointed NetBeans to the correct MinGW version.
   To do that, go to `Project Properties` **>** `Build` **>** `Tool Collection` **>** `...` **>** `Tool Collection Manager` and
   there you can set the path to the proper g++ version.
2. Make sure that you have set the correct compiler options:

   `Project Properties` **>** `Build` **>** `C++ Compiler` **>**

   `Compilation Line` **>** `Additional Options`

   set it to: `-std=c++11`

Comment: where can I access such a thing on netbeans?

Comment: @LynnFavor I added the information :) If you are on Linux, just make sure the compiler is g++ or clang, the option will be the same

Comment: those quotes didn't help me, but this did: Simpler Steps:

Open the project
File menu > Project Properties
Under Build > C++ Compiler > C++ Standard > C++14/ C++11

Comment: Thanks Geoffroy for referencing that author. One of the other users on that page helped.

Comment: However the warning is still there, even though I finally see my desired output (Thanks again). I lost you on ```compilation line``` and onwards. :(