# What is the meaning of "range-based for loop is a C++11 extension" and what is expected expression?

Tags: c++

This is my code :

```
class YouTubeChannel {
    public:
    string Name;
    string OwnerName;
    int SubsCount;
    list<string> PublishedVideos;

};



int main(){

    YouTubeChannel ytChannel;
    ytChannel.Name = "Wonder World";
    ytChannel.OwnerName = "Sally";
    ytChannel.SubsCount = 1200;
    ytChannel.PublishedVideos = {"Victoria Memorial", "Red Fort", "Monument"};

    cout<<"Name : "<<ytChannel.Name<<endl;
    cout<<"Owner Name : "<<ytChannel.OwnerName<<endl;
    cout<<"Subs count : "<<ytChannel.SubsCount<<endl;
    cout<<"Videos : "<<endl;
    for(string videoTitle : ytChannel.PublishedVideos){
        cout<<videoTitle<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting two errors :

```
 error: expected expression
    ytChannel.PublishedVideos = {"Victoria Memorial", "Red Fort", "Monument"};
                                ^
 warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
    for(string videoTitle : ytChannel.PublishedVideos){
                          ^
```

Kindly plz tell me what shall i do so that I don't get this errors??

Expected Output is :

```
Name : Wonder World
Owner Name : Sally
Subscriber Count : 1200
Videos : 
Victoria Memorial
Red Fort
Monument
```

Comment: It means that you have to tell your compiler to use The C++11 (or greater) Standard; this is usually done with a switch passed to the compiler when compiling.  IDE's usually have options to set this flag.  How are you compiling your program and/or what is the command line you are using?

Comment: use c++ 11 or greater compiler

Comment: What compiler are you using? It seems the one you use doesn't know about C++11 yet. Or you are missing a commandline option to enable C++11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension \[-Wc++11-extensions\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623470/warning-range-based-for-loop-is-a-c11-extension-wc11-extensions)

Comment: Thanks for all of your answers but how do I use c++11 or greater compiler. Btw I am using mac and this g++ -std=c++11 is not working!

Comment: _"...is not working..."_ is not a problem we can fix - what is not working: the command line, the same problem, something else ?  What version of g++ are you using ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> warning: range-based for loop is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]

What this means is that you are compiling your code with a version of `C++` selected that is prior to `C++11`, but as an extension, your compiler is going to allow you to do it anyway. However, the code is not portable because not all compilers will allow it. That is why it is warning you.

If you want your code to be portable, you should either stop using the range-based-for, or compile with the `C++11` version (or greater) of the `C++ Standard` selected.

This may mean adding a flag like `-std=c++11` to your compile command, but it varies by compiler and development environment.

I would also advise configuring your compiler to adhere to strict standards if you want portable code. For example, with `GCC` or `clang` this can be done by adding `-pedantic-errors` to the compile command.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer but how do I use c++11 or greater compiler. Btw I am using mac and this g++ -std=c++11 is not working!

Comment: @AditiSingh What command do you normally use to compile your program? Also what version of the compiler are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You could compile it through command line like this:

`g++ -std=c++11 -o name_of_program name_of_file.cpp`

If you run your program, it should get your expected output.