# Configuring C++11/14 in Mac Terminal by default

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to use `c++11/14` features like range-based loops, but get a warning while doing `g++ program.cpp`. If done with compiler flag `g++ -std=c++11 program.cpp` the warning goes away. Is there a way to use `c++11/14` by default on the `g++` command (i.e without passing compiler flag every time).

Please explain to someone with limited knowledge of compilers and only need the `c++11/14` features for competitive programming problems (even if it's a bad idea in general, maybe due to backward compatibility?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Update your g++

According to [g++ documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Standards.html#C_002b_002b-Language)

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is -std=gnu++17.

You are probably using an older version of g++. You can check it using by running `g++ --version` in your terminal. If you are using Linux, you can also extract your default c++ standard from g++ manual with the command `man g++ | col -b | grep -B 1 -e '-std.* default'` in your terminal.

If you do not want to update your g++, you can also set a command alias by putting something like `alias g+++='g++ -std=c++14'` in your `.bashrc`

Comment: Not quite correct assumption. Default language is defined by configuration of build chain when it was compiled. E.g. on mac compilers were defaulted to C++98 for many years.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a gcc version > 4.9.3 use this command: `g++ -std=c++14 program.cpp`

If you're using an older version than that use `g++ -std=c++1y program.cpp`

Note: Consider adding the `-Wall` flag before `program.cpp` in your command to get warnings, they help you way more than you'd think!

Tip: If you're a starting developer and don't want too steep of a learning curve, try using an IDE before going full command-line.

EDIT: If you want a command to be "the default" you can add something like `alias mycc='g++ -std=c++14 -Wall'` in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file (see [this link](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/04/about-bash_profile-and-bashrc-on-macos/)), then you'll be able to use `mycc program.cpp`

Comment: OP wants to avoid typing `-std=c++14` if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I know some instance where a "kind"  developer who also was  a root on a shared compiling host used this to make all warnings into errors. It kindaworked, there is no longer 7k warnings inthat project :P